What is the biblical basis for claiming that salvation is an individual decision?
This article  from a Christian web site, has suggested that salvation is an individual decision and a relationship with God is an intensely personal decision.  It also says obedience and surrender to the Holy Spirit are individual decisions that cannot be made for us by others.
Here is another article that says we can have a personal relationship with God the moment we realise our need for Him, admit we are sinners, and in faith “receive Jesus Christ as Saviour.”
No mention of the Holy Spirit convicting us of the enormity of our sin so we realise our guilt and our hopelessness.  No mention of this awareness leading us to heartfelt repentance.   Is that all anybody has to do to be saved, simply decide to receive the gift?
Does the Bible say that all a person has to do to be saved it to “accept” the “offer” of salvation, and that it is up to the individual to make that decision?  It’s known as “easy-believism” – once we make the decision to accept what’s on offer then we become the children of God and receive the Holy Spirit “who will begin to work in our hearts.”
Specifically, does the Bible say it’s up to the individual to either accept or reject salvation?
Update from the Got Questions July Report: 9,016 persons (worldwide) have made a profession of faith in Jesus Christ (in July) by clicking on the G.Q. link which says "I have accepted Christ today".
In order to present a balanced view, I post links to two Got Questions articles that clarify their views on belief in Christ https://www.gotquestions.org/Bible-belief.html  and the signs of saving faith https://www.gotquestions.org/signs-saving-faith.html
However, the main question still stands - what is the biblical basis for claiming that salvation is an individual decision?

You are going to get very different answers for this based upon the sect in question. You'll probably want to specify what denomination(s) you would like to hear the answer from (maybe do multiple posts, one per sect). Some will assert that all you need to do is to repent and accept the Lord and you'll be saved. Others (Reformed Theology) will assert that if God pre-ordained you to be saved then you will be saved (and if he pre-ordained you for hell then you are damned). Others - like myself - maintain that there is a combination of grace + works. Scripture says you must persevere to be saved

"The sect in question" is an evangelical web site of no specific denomination. I simply want to know whether the Bible supports this evangelical view - one that has become much more common over recent decades.

The convicting work of the Holy Spirit is necessary but it can be resisted and rejected to the point where true repentance is unrealized. The condemned have no excuse and the redeemed have no boast.

I think you're missing the focus of such a statement: the individual decision is not meant to deny the massive role of God in our salvation, but to counter the idea that salvation comes through membership in the church or a Christian family. Those articles are not about easy believism, both do discuss the role of the Spirit and the transformation the Gospel brings to our lives.

@curiousdannii  The articles downplay the massive role of God in salvation and give a false impression to people who are not yet Christians. As a mature Christian who came to saving faith in 1996 the wording in these articles shocked me. They make light of how God views sin and the need to repent.

@MikeBorden Without the convicting work of the Holy Spirit that leads to true repentance, there is a very real danger that an individual might think they've done all that is necessary, that they have been saved because "they came to Christ" yet they have not been born again, the Holy Spirit does not indwell them and they do not produce the fruit of the Spirit. The convicting work of the Holy Spirit is essential. To resist and reject Him is a deliberate and conscious act by the individual who is presented with the Gospel.

@Lesley The wording 'irresistible grace' has been commandeered by those who have a truncated gospel ("tulip") but the original doctrine was sound in that the Grace of God is such that if God chooses one in Christ, before the foundation of the world, then that Divine choice will not be frustrated. The Everlasting Love of God will overwhelm the soul, Grace will be effective and that person shall be saved. Easy believism has permeated far deeper into Evangelicalism than is usually realised.

@NigelJ - I agree, especially that it is God who chooses us.

@Lesley Indeed. 'Twas grace that taught my heart to fear ; and grace my fears relieved ; how precious did that grace appear, the hour I first believed'.

There appears to be two distinct issues in the question--"easy believing" and "individual decisions". I think most mature Christians understand that easy believism is false while it is true that repentance and/or faith are decisions that someone else cannot make for you.

"salvation is an individual decision", "relationship with God is an intensely personal decision", "obedience and surrender to the Holy Spirit are individual decisions that cannot be made for us by others" — Which of these points are you disagreeing with?

@RayButterworth What I find deeply upsetting about the Got Questions articles is that it gives an impression to the unwary, the new Christian, or the person who does not know anything about salvation, that it's dead easy to become a Christian and be saved. Saved from what? Who does the saving? I don't intend to engage any further, only to say that it is my view that some evangelical organisations play down what God has done, in Christ Jesus, to save us from the enormity of our sins. The answer I accepted explains a lot.

@DarkMalthorp - You've highlighted the problem, that "most mature Christians understand that easy believism is false while it is true that repentance and/or faith are decisions that someone else cannot make for you." It's the immature Christians or the people who are trying to find out about Christianity that could come away with the wrong idea after reading some of the on-line stuff published by some evangelical organisations.

@Lesley, so I think you're saying that the process of salvation requires more than a simple personal decision to be saved (e.g. it requires being called by God, and God's becoming part of one's life), not that the acceptance or rejection of that call isn't a decision that one can make (e.g. predestination).

@RayButterworth What I believe is that salvation is the work of God from start to finish. By the Holy Spirit, those who are called and repent, turning to God for forgiveness of sin, are accepted by Him. Some evangelicals seem to have it the wrong way round! Can we agree that God calls, the Holy Spirit convicts, and if we then turn to God in repentance we are adopted by Him into His family? It's always good to explore these things, but at the end of the day, it is God who does the saving, yes?

A difficulty with this question is that, although individuals either receive salvation or they do not, salvation from God is not dependent on any "decision" we choose to make.
The popular trend amongst many Protestant groups these days seems to amount to salvation being granted by "making a decision for Christ". The idea is that God has done nearly everything towards providing salvation, but that it requires the individual's assent to "clinch the deal". Then God gets the green light to give salvation to that individual. If people don't decide to accept what's "on offer", then what God has done cannot go any further.
In the two cases raised in the question, it is true that only one of them mentions the Holy Spirit, but that (I suggest) is to miss the point of the problem, hence the way I have described this modern idea of individuals making their own decisions about salvation. Both groups say the individual's choice is essential, even though one includes mention of the Holy Spirit. That does not alter the fact that both are urging individuals to accept what's on offer, and anybody can receive salvation if they make the right choice. They are both about decision-making by people.
Both grossly misrepresent the gospel of salvation. There is no biblical basis for claiming that we have to do something to 'trigger' as it were, the Holy Spirit's power in bringing us to salvation. There is no biblical basis for claiming that we have to decide "to receive Christ" in order to receive salvation. Many will select Bible verses and interpret them that way, but no interpretation that puts people in control of the outcome of salvation can be of God.
Only this morning I was singing an old hymn written nearly 200 years ago, which wonderfully conveys the biblical truth about what we individuals can never do to achieve salvation, contrasted with what God does to gift us undeserving sinners with a deep, personal relationship with him. Here are five verses:

Not what these hands have done can save this guilty soul;  Not what
this toiling flesh has borne can make my spirit whole.
Not what I feel or do can give me peace with God;  Not all my prayers
and sighs and tears can bear my awful load.
Thy work alone, O Christ, can ease this weight of sin;  Thy blood
alone, O Lamb of God, can give me peace within.
Thy love to me, O God, not mine, O Lord, to Thee, can rid me of this
dark unrest, and set my spirit free.
Thy grace alone, O God, to me can pardon speak; Thy power alone, O Son
of God, can this sore bondage break.
Horatius Bonar (1808 - 1889)

Not a word, let alone even a hint, about the individual deciding for Christ, or agreeing to be obedient to the Holy Spirit and deciding to 'surrender'. That is modern jargon. Such lyric-writers of old knew that the Holy Spirit begins to give desperate anguish of conscience to sinners before they may even have learned that there is this blessed Holy Spirit. They knew that when God begins to draw a person to conviction of sin, they first have to despair of ever being able to do anything to save themselves; that it seems impossible that they could ever be viewed by God as 'worthy' of being saved. They have to be cast upon their knees with the horrible truth of what faces sinners, were it not for God's moving in them. God acts first. The Holy Spirit acts first. The hearing of the gospel of salvation follows. And that is what gives the person hope. Christ has already done it all! When he cried "It is finished" from the cross, it was accomplished. Every soul whom God would save - in past history, at the time of Christ's ministry, and every soul thereafter until the time Christ returns, will be drawn and brought to spiritual life through the faith of Jesus Christ. Without that work of grace, nobody can understand their true plight and the only remedy. God does that work of grace. God gifts them the faith needed. With hindsight, after they are brought to spiritual life, then they see the way the Spirit of God has striven with them, and those are precisely what those lyrics show.
Those lyrics are no longer sung in modern congregations that stress the importance of individuals making "a decision for Christ", either with or without inclusion of mentioning the Holy Spirit. The gospel of salvation begins with God, continues with Christ, and ends with the Holy Spirit's conviction of sin. Well, not "ends", as that's just the start of walking in God-given faith in newness of life. Making "a decision for Christ" never got anybody through the strait gate into life eternal.
P.S. the first link is not about becoming a Christian by making a decision; go to this for that - https://www.gotquestions.org/become-a-Christian.html It's full of "Why should I become a Christian?" "What should I do to..." etc. All about the individual and deciding things. That is why that non-denominational site is misleading, I suggest. When it comes to "what to do", it urges individuals to "Make a Decision for Christ".

That article is deeply distressing. As a Reformed Protestant, I believe and know, experientially, that salvation is entirely the work of God, from start to finish. It is the Holy Spirit who convicts us of sin, and without that conviction (which should bring us to our knees before a holy and righteous God) we are lost.

@ t The question at hand( I think) is whether or not a sinner can resist that conviction of the Holy Spirit.

@MikeBorden - The question at hand is not about any deliberate resistance towards the Gospel and the Holy Spirit. The question at hand is about the false impression those articles give that it is up to the individual to "accept" - that they have a part to play in "deciding" for Christ and then they will be "saved".  Those article are dangerously misleading.

@Lesley In John 1:11-12, "received" is in the active tense.  Some actively receive Him and some do not.  Not wishing division, I'll say no more on this.


Does the Bible say it’s up to the individual to either accept or
reject salvation?

Biblically, there is no clear yes-or-no answer to your question. That is because God has created His image bearers to have volition. By volition, I mean that every human being has a will. (Notice I do not use the expression free will, since the level of freeness will always be debatable along the Calvin-Arminius divide in the church universal.)
On the human level, to have a relationship with another person requires accession on both sides. I can sincerely desire to have a relationship with another person, but if that person chooses to reject my overtures of friendship, he or she may never be in a relationship with me.
Why should having a relationship with God be any different? Yes, He is God, and God is sovereign, and we are not, but then are not we also sovereign in a way? I have the ability to say no to another person's offer to be in a relationship with me, and I can continue saying no until the day I die.
Safe to say the author of the articles you cite in your question does not reject the importance of the role of the Holy Spirit in making a relationship with God possible. I'm positive the author would, in another posting, mention the crucial role that God's Holy Spirit plays in the process of regeneration.
Clearly, God's many invitations in Scripture to His image bearers to be in a close relationship with Him do not make sense if we can say neither yes nor no to the invitation.
The charge of Joshua to the children of Israel rings true to this day:

"Choose for yourselves this day whom you will serve . . ." (Joshua
24:15).

And Joshua's response:

"As for me and my household, we will serve the Lord" (Joshua 24:15).

God is not in the business of forcing His image bearer to accept or reject Him. Can we accept His proffer of grace, mercy, and forgiveness without the drawing and enabling power of His Holy Spirit? No. Do we have the capability of rejecting that proffer? Yes.
We, as sentient human beings created in the image of God are caught in an antinome, or paradox. We have the God-given ability to reject God, but we also have the God-given ability to accept God. On the one hand, we have God helping us to say yes, but on the other hand we have God allowing us to say no. Is there a contradiction therein? No.

When there seems to be a contradiction between two passages, my approach is to assume I'm not understanding something.  Some may have the approach to just ignore one of the passages.

@rhetorician – My question is not about making an informed decision to either accept or reject salvation (as per what the Bible says about it). It's about the claims of some people "that salvation is an individual decision" and it's up to the individual to accept the gift being offered, to choose Christ, and that, by so doing, they are automatically "saved". But saved from what? Do they even have the first idea of how God views sin and what biblical salvation is all about? Those articles are dangerously misleading to people who have not yet understood why they must repent.

@WGroleau: I could be wrong, but I think your "approach" does not make room for antinome and paradox. Jesus's teaching on losing one's life to find it and finding one's life only to lose it poses a contradiction, but many believers understand the teaching perfectly.

@Lesley: I could be wrong, but your exegesis of the two passages you cite reflects a mature understanding of the "meat" of the salvation story and of conversion. (Yes, I read your profile and how you were converted 28 years ago.) A babe in Christ understands very little about the theological mechanics of conversion. He or she needs milk. "Once I was blind, but now I see." That sort of thing. Is "easy believism" an oversimplification of a deep and somewhat mysterious transaction between a sinner and God? Yes. It starts out that way, but it CAN (and does) deepen and mature over time.

@rhetorician I agree that God never forces anyone either to accept or to reject, but look at the link to the Got Questions article Anne posted. It's the assumption that all a person has to do is say "I accept Christ" when it is the other way around. Ah, well, at least we can be assured that all who are given by the Father into Jesus' hand will never be lost. They know who really belong to them.

@Lesley: True that. "Nevertheless, God’s solid foundation stands firm, sealed with this inscription: 'The Lord knows those who are his,' and, 'Everyone who confesses the name of the Lord must turn away from wickedness'” (2 Tim 2:19).

Technically the Bible does answer your question with a Yes, to back up my claim, I will refer you to the book of Saint John where it is written that the decision to accept or reject the offer of salvation has been left for an individual to make.
John 3:16

For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life

Pay attention to the phrase, whosever believes in him which implies it is up to a person to either believe in Jesus or reject him. Salvation from the flood was offered to the men in the days of Noah, those men had to make a decision to either believe in Noah's words and go inside the boat or reject his warning. God does not force anyone to do anything except in special circumstances such as Jonah. God wants people to serve him out of love and that is why he has given them liberty of choice with consequences.

As someone else mentioned, there are several instances of us being urged to choose.  And as far as I know, every time Jesus referred to damnation or condemnation, He always explicitly or implicitly related it to the person's choices.  On the other hand, “No one can come to me unless the Father who sent me draws them, …”

Your answer could be improved by quoting from the Bible any passages that support what Jesus actually said. Unfortunately, Bible Hub demands I agree to their cookies before reading the texts - something I will not do - so it would be helpful if you could say which N.T. books, chapter and verses you have in mind and I can look them up.

I don't worry about cookies.  I just installed an app that deletes them, along with just about anything that contains the string "google."  And if you see a link ferom biblegateway or biblehub or bible.is or bible.com, you can figure out the reference from the URI without clicking on it.

Appreciate the advice but I'm an I.T. dunce and I don't know how to install software applications either on my laptop or my mobile phone. A bit of a technology lost cause, me!

When you point to the link (alias "hover"), in most browsers, the full URI appears either near the pointer or near the bottom of the window.  For the link above, it ends with "john/6-44.htm".  If you have a local friend with "geek skills," he/she can probably show you how to set up your browser to auto-delete cookies.  There are also browsers available that are pretty good at preventing websites from tracking you.
